# Using Overleaf and my Glossar and Acrynom list is not showing

Tags: glossaries, overleaf

So I have a template from my University, that I use to write my thesis on.
I have seperated files for my chapters and sections, literature, glossary and acrynoms. all my files are called properly on my main .tex except for glossaries and acrynoms I keep getting these following errors
[image: this error basically repeats itself with every glossary command i use in my chapters]

```
\newglossaryentry{Backward Chaining}{
        name= backward chaining,
        description={eine Methode, die mit Zielen beginnt und rückwärts arbeitet, um festzustellen, welche Fakten behauptet werden müssen, damit die Ziele erreicht werden können.}
}
```

this was an example of a glossary entery i have and the following code is my main.text code

```
    \documentclass[
  a4paper,            % DIN A4
  DIV=10,             % Schriftgröße und Satzspiegel
  oneside,            % einseitiger Druck
  BCOR=5mm,           % Bindungskorrektur
  parskip=half,       % Halber Abstand zwischen Absätzen
  numbers=noenddot,   % Kein Punkt hinter Kapitelnummern
  bibtotoc,           % Literaturverzeichnis im Inhaltsverzeichnis
  listof=totoc        % Abbildungs- und Tabellenverzeichnis im Inhaltsverzeichnis
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{../style/thesisstyle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries           % create all glossary entries (remember: run makeglossaries manually)
\loadglsentries{thesisglossaries.tex}  % load acronym, symbol and glossarie entries

\sisetup{locale = DE}     % siunitx locale setup
%\DeclareSIUnit \fps{fps}  % a custom unit (usage: \SI{24}{\fps})

\begin{document}
\input{configuration/configuration}    % load all settings

\hyphenation{Ba-che-lor-the-sis Mas-ter-the-sis}

% Cover page here, no page number
\ICoverPage

% PDF Metadata
\input{../style/metadata}

% Titlepage is page one even if the number is not shown.
\pagenumbering{roman}
% Title page here
\input{../style/titlepage}

% Abstract page here
\input{../style/abstractpage}

% Table of contents here
\tableofcontents

% List of figures here
\IListOfFigures

% List of tables here
\IListOfTables

% List of accronyms here
\IListOfAccronyms

% List of symbols here
\IListOfSymbols

% Uncomment if list of source code is needed (rarely).
%\lstlistoflistings  % requires package listings, needs to uncommenting of usepackage

% path to the chapters folder is set to find the images used there
\graphicspath{ {./chapters/} }

% Chapters
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{template_thesis/chapters/first_chapter/first_chapter}
\input{chapters/second_chapter}
\input{chapters/third_chapter}


% Add additional chapters here

%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliographystyle{dinat}
\bibliography{literature}

% Appendix
\appendix
\input{appendix/example_appendix}

\IGlossary
\input{thesisglossaries.tex}

\Istatement

\end{document}
```

i would also like to mention it does not print my the places where i used my glossary definition in the text. Is there something i could edit with my code that will fix the glossary and acrynom problems, because this error has been accumulating itsself?

thanks

Comment: Have you defined `AI` in your thesisglossaries.tex? If it contains all the `\newglossaryentry`, then it should just be used in `\loadglsentries{thesisglossaries.tex}` but not `\input{thesisglossaries.tex}` later. We also don't know what `\IGlossary` does and whether it affects how the glossaries is processed.

Comment: hello, 
yes I did this Error that i displayed I have it about 44 times for all the defined `\newglossaryentry`. I also tried `\loadglsentries{thesisglossaries.tex}` without `\input{thesisglossaries.tex}` and the other way around I also commented `ÌGlossary` out and using `\printglossary`only. it was still fruitless.

Comment: These are quite hard to debug without a complete MWE i.e. a small but complete and compilable example that we can compile to inspect the actual errors. If you are unable to post an MWE here, it may be best to contact support@overleaf.com with your project's ID, so that the support team can have a look.

Comment: Hey, first of all i want to thank you for giving me the idea to contact the support! it fixed my problems, there were several problems to it not working. one is due to the fact that my main file should be outside of all folders, which i did not do the second one is `\newacronym{ai}{AI}{Artificial Intelligence}` i wrote in my code `\acrfull{AI}` and it should be `acrfull{ai}` because the acrynom uses the first keyword as its label basically and it is case sensitve. just thought of coming back and sharing the answer in case you or others are interested now or in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all i want to thank you for giving me the idea to contact the support! it fixed my problems, there were several problems to it not working. one is due to the fact that my main file should be outside of all folders, which i did not do the second one is `\newacronym{ai}{AI}{Artificial Intelligence}` i wrote in my code `\acrfull{AI}` and it should be `acrfull{ai}` because the acrynom uses the first keyword as its label basically and it is case sensitve. just thought of coming back and sharing the answer in case you or others are interested now or in the future!

these 2 mistakes were the obsticale in making my glossary function normally